# How to make a JQgrid with inline editing that populates with php call to server

Tags: php, jqgrid

I am able to populate a grid as well as perform update, both via a php call to server.  I cannot seem to construct a grid that does both.  In the code below, I have both url and editurl.  Both point to the same php page, but I think this is necessary.  On the php page, I am collecting the contents of the cells via POST and printing them to a file.  I know this code is accurate because it works when I use it with a grid that only saves data and doesn't attempt to populate with a php server call.  Being fairly new to JQGrid, I'm not sure how data is saved and sent.  Also note that I had to use datatype: 'local' to save the data, but I have to use datatype: 'xml' to populate the grid.  Perhaps this is the problem?

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
url:'functions.php',
datatype:'xml',
mtype:'POST',
colNames:['Label','Account_Num','Amount', 'Type Code', 'Record Code', 'Sequence','Actions'],
colModel :[
{name:'label', index:'label', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
{name:'cntrct_id', index:'cntrct_id', width:150, align:'center', sortable:true},
{name:'amount', index:'amount', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
{name:'type_cd', index:'type_cd', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false, editable:true},
{name:'rec_cd', index:'rec_cd', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false},
{name:'db_seq', index:'db_seq', width:150, align:'center', sortable:false},
{   name:'actions',
classes:'jg_actions',
formatter:"actions",
editable:false,
sortable:false,
resizable:false,
fixed:true,
width:120,
formatoptions:{
    keys:true,
    delbutton:true,
    onSuccess: function(response){

    },
},
},
],
editurl: 'functions.php',
postData: { 
action:'popGrid', 
sqlCount:sqlCount, 
sqlSelect:sqlSelect, 
sqlSelect2:sqlSelect2, 
label1:label1, 
label2:label2,},
onSelectRow: function(id){
    if(id && id!==lastSel){
        jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastSel);
    jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true);
    lastSel=id;
    }
},

pager: '#pager',
rowNum:100,
rowList:[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000],
sortname: 'cntrct_id',
sortorder: 'desc',
viewrecords: true,
caption: 'Adjustments'
}); 


<?php

$label = $_POST['label'];
$cntrct_id = $_POST['cntrct_id'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$type_cd = $_POST['type_cd'];
$rec_cd = $_POST['rec_cd'];
$db_seq = $_POST['db_seq'];
$myfile = "text.txt";
$fh = fopen($myfile,'a');
fwrite($fh,$label.' '.$cntrct_id.' '.$amount.' '.$type_cd.' '.$rec_cd.' '.$db_seq);
fclose($fh);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused on XML vs Local datatypes.  What the datatype specifies is where the data to feed the grid will come from.  Local means that you are providing a variable that has data in it from some other portion on the client side where XML means that you will provide XML formatted data from a URL. (Server side process)

You should be able to use Firebug/Chrome to see the data your grid sends out after an update, the format it is in and where it is going. After your edit, the post to your `functions.php` your grid should reload with that reload reflecting the changes to your dataset from your edit.

Comment: Changed a few things around and now the file IS being written to.  This is a simple oversight on my part.  Thanks for your clarification, Mark.

Comment: Hey, no problem, I know it's tough to find the inbetween basic stuff and the very in depth stuff and you just needed a little nudge in the right direction.